# Numerous Permission Denied Errors Using /etc/cron.daily

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

Good Afternoon All,

I'm attempting to run a shell script (Full Path: **/home/aaron/grads/get_nomads/bash/rtma.sh**) by adding it into the /etc/cron.daily folder.

Nothing was working so, I did some research online and found that running    `run-parts -v /etc/cron.daily` may help reveal the issue.

I did so and got the following error messages:

```
[aaron@arrakis ~]run-parts -v /etc/cron.daily
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/0anacron
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apport
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/crash/./.lock’: Operation not permitted
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apt
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/cracklib-runtime
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
cp: cannot create regular file ‘dpkg.status’: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch ‘dpkg.status’: Permission denied
savelog: could not touch dpkg.status
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/dpkg exited with return code 4
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: 6: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate: cannot create   status.clean:     Permission denied
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: 7: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate: cannot create    status.clean:     Permission denied
mv: cannot stat ‘status.clean’: No such file or directory
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 103: Operation not permitted
error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/man-db
start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 12 (Operation not permitted)
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/man-db exited with return code 2
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
/usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/mlocate exited with return code 1
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/passwd
cp: cannot create regular file ‘passwd.bak’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘group.bak’: Permission denied
cp: cannot open ‘/etc/shadow’ for reading: Permission denied
cp: cannot open ‘/etc/gshadow’ for reading: Permission denied
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/passwd exited with return code 1
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/upstart
```

I need some help...

Thanks!

Comment: you supposed to run it as root (e.g.: `sudo`)